# Batch to prompt for RDP shadowing session

Tags: batch-file, rdp

So this is what I have in a batch file.
What I need it to do is

- Show the current RDP sessions.
- Prompt for the session to shadow
- User input the session ID.

Then the `mstsc /shadow: /control /noconsentprompt` is executed ***with the session ID indicated at prompt*** where `/shadow:X` is

This is what I have but how to I insert the session ID chosen by user input into the /shadow: field ?

Thanks for your help.

```
    @echo off
    qwinsta
    set /p id=Enter Session ID:
    echo %id%

    mstsc /shadow: /control /noconsentprompt
```

Comment: What is stopping you from putting the `%id%` variable after `/shadow:`?

Comment: Variables are the core of any programming.  If you couldn't use them with a command you need to execute you would never get anything done with a program.  You could have just browsed a couple of the batch file questions just to see examples of how variables are used.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you set a bookmark for https://ss64.com/cmd - this is a _very_ good reference site for using the Windows command prompt CMD.EXE.

Comment: When taking user input via `Set /P` it is strongly recommended that the input be validated as suitable for the intended use to avoid unhandled failure, or worse, code injection. Search out examples of such on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to enable [delayed expansion of variables](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), at which point you would write your `mstsc` command as

```
mstsc /shadow:!id! /control /noconsentprompt
```

Comment: Based on the code example they have given, I see no reason to use delayed expansion.

Comment: @Squashman - Perhaps not, but I've had ... irregular ... results when I don't.

Comment: Does this look correct ?

`@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

qwinsta

set /p id=Enter Session ID:

echo %id%

mstsc /shadow:!id! /control /noconsentprompt`

Comment: @SDK - If the `echo %id%` prints what you expect, then you can use `/shadow:%id%` instead of `/shadow:!id!` - but otherwise, yes, that's what you'd do.